# Datastore read policy setting in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

In Google App Engine I'm trying to set the Datastore read policy using Go.

Python has this ability using `read_policy = db.EVENTUAL_CONSISTENCY` but there seems to be no Go equivalent. You can see that this section is missing from the Go documentation.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Data_consistency
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Data_consistency

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have raised an issue here.  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality has now been added.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.EventualConsistency

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems there's currently no way to specify *eventual consistency for ancestor queries* (other kinds of queries are always either strong or eventually consistent).

You could create a new issue on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request

If you do create one, please post here the ID so that others can star it.